# What is the maximum voltage at which I can operate a Z80 without causing problems?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-divider, z80

I created a small circuit that takes 220 V power from a power plug and passes it through some resistors (68 Ω and 2.8 Ω) to output 9.1 V.

Then, it uses 2 more resistors (3.3 Ω and 4.7 Ω) to divide the 9 V into 5.344 V.

I think the Z80 can withstand 5.344 V, but I'd like to know what the maximum voltage is I can use to power it (at 20, 10, or 8 Mhz so it doesn't desync with the VGA signal).

(Edit: This is not a live circuit, I'm doing a test in a PCB simulator.)

Comment: **This is a disaster waiting to happen.** The circuit must be considered live and since you mention VGA that means the screen on the connectors must be considered live. With 5 V USB isolated power supplies so cheap these days a resistive dropper mains supply would be absolute stupidity.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic?  It doesn't seem like powering a Z80 from 220V with just a restive voltage divider is a good idea.

Comment: **You should not, ever, power a low voltage load directly from mains using only a resistor divider!** Please  use a proper power supply. Besides that, a resistor divider with a variable load will not work. The maximum voltage is in the data sheet but remember the Z80 has/had many different manufacturers. However, you should just use a 5V stabilized power supply.

Comment: 220V AC (RMS) from the power grid is higher voltage when rectified to DC; over 300V DC. Even without a diode explicitly connected, the Z80 itself will "work" as a diode (for a fraction of a second, before it gets smoked to death). And even worse than that, there's no isolation to protect against accidental line/neutral swap from putting 220V AC on your external VGA monitor's ground; or putting 220V AC directly on any person close enough to any exposed wiring or external connectors. Code violation, health/safety hazard, etc.

Comment: The resistor values you mention (71 Ohm in total) will make the "supply" consume hundreds of Watts and most probably make your resistors vaporize in an instant.

Comment: Also, the current drawn by your resistive dropper will be 220 / (68 + 2.8) = **3.1 A** (for a load that probably requires about 50 mA). Power dissipated in the 68 ohm resistor will be **653 W** which is more than half a one-bar electric heater and all going to waste. A USB power supply will probably waste < 1 W.

Comment: **Don't do it!!** As all the comments say, it's an accident waiting to happen in so many ways.

Comment: Even if you are just using a simulator, never ever do this, PLEASE! Such a schematic will sneak somehow into some public, and someone might finally build a real one - and **die**. Would you like to be responsible for this? -- The simulator you use will have some sort of power supply with 5V DC output, for sure. Simply use that.

Comment: I hope you are kidding! McGyver would have used a toaster and a shaver motor in series to get 5V.. (don't try that either!)

Comment: No mention of rectification.  Odds are Z80 and negative voltages releases the magic smoke. If this is not a joke and you are honestly considering doing it, step away from electronics and consider a safer field, like parachuting without the chute.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat stupid power supply circuits are still less dangerous than parachuting without a parachute. Especially if you stand well clear when plugging them in. Don't forget to be recording with your phone in case there are fireworks, and upload them to TikTok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5 Volts +- 10 % from the [Datasheet](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/Zilog/Z80/Z80_DataBook.pdf). And your description with the resistor-network straight on the power line sounds frightening, but I hope you know what you are doing because you don't asked for this one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put in a rectifier at a minimum.  4 diodes, in a diamond pattern (a quick google will give you an idea) AC goes in, DC comes out - then measure your voltage out of that, and then calculate your resistor dividers.  Preferably, you put a step-down transformer in first before the diodes as well, but in a pinch....

This isn't a recommended way to do a power supply, but it can work for a quick bench project as long as safety is acknowledged, and it's upgraded with a real power supply later down the line.

But, to be fair, who doesn't have 5-10 USB wall warts laying around these days?  Those put out 5V, which is just about perfect for a Z80.